# How to compare objects using operator < or > in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, object, compare

How do I compare two objects of a custom class in Objective-C? I try to overloading the

`- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(id)other;`

method. This works great if I call the method manually

```
if ([obj1 compare:obj2] == NSOrderedDescending) {  
    // do something  
}
```

Is there any way that I can do it like this?

```
if (obj1 > obj2) {
    // do something
}
```

Or is there another method that I need to overload?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the comparison? In case you want to insert individual items in a sorted order into a collection I recommend taking a look at `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:`. It is available for `NSArray` in Mac OS X v10.6 and later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible, since objective C doesn't have operator overloading. You are comparing pointer values.

Comment: Thank you for the statment. Now I can understand why comparing with > sometimes seems to work. Next time I will try not to compare pointer value. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is for your class you can define comparisons to everything that make sense to compare with.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    // your stuff
}
- (BOOL)isGreaterThanNumber:(NSNumber *)otherNumber;
+ (BOOL)compare:(MyClass *)myClass toNumber:(NSNumber *)otherNumber;
```

With well-named functions this isn't terribly different than overloading although yes it prevents you from using > and <.  The actual code you write should be identical though as if overloading were included.